# Magento: using getModel to get product and category

Tags: php, magento

I have some code that returns an array of product details including a url_path. To create a link to this product I have to know the category and subcategory of the product. Unfortunately out all the data this method returns neither the category or sub category are pulled out.

Here is the code I have that gets a product:

```
$product_id = array(231, 230,229,228);

foreach ($product_id as $id){
    $productDetails = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getData();
    echo $productDetails['url_path'].'<br />';
}
```

Is it possible to get the category and subcategory for each product?

Comment: remember: a product can belong to more then one category/subcategory. different paths (shop.tld/product.html, shop.tld/cat/subcat/product.html and shop.tld/cat2/subcat3/product.html) can point to the same product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for

```
foreach ($product_id as $id){
    $categoryIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getCategoryIds();    
}
```

which will return you an array of category ids that the product belongs to.

Comment: $productDetails is an array though? How can I access the method?

Comment: Sorry use Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getCategoryIds(). I will update my original post

Answer (score 0):

Better way not to miss something with rewrites is to use core functionality.
Mage_Catalog module has own url model, with which product urls can be modified.

So, the code will be:

```
$product_id = array(231, 230,229,228);

$urlModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/url');
foreach ($product_id as $id) {
    $urlModel->refreshProductRewrite($id);
}
```

And it is no need to retrieve category ids for this purpose.