# Magento: get the lowest price of a grouped product by product ID?

Tags: php, magento

I have a piece of code that returns product data including a price. However for a grouped product it doesn't give the price.

Is there a way to take the ID of the grouped product and get the lowest price of the group?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $id_array = strip_tags($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('homepage-newest-product')->toHtml());
    $product_id = explode(',',$id_array);


    foreach ($product_id as $id):
        $productDetails = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getData();
        //var_dump($productDetails);
    ?>
    <li class="a-center span-3">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . $productDetails['url_path']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $media_url . 'catalog/product' . $productDetails['thumbnail']; ?>" width="80" height="80"/></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() . $productDetails['url_path']; ?>" class="clearfix"><?php echo $productDetails['name']; ?></a>
        <?php if($productDetails['price']): ?>
        <span>
        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($productDetails['price'],true,false) ?>
        </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Preferebly I'd have a function that takes the grouped ID and looks up the lowest price of the group, then returns the price.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method looks like below:

```
public function prepareGroupedProductPrice($groupedProduct)
{
    $aProductIds = $groupedProduct->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($groupedProduct->getId());

    $prices = array();
    foreach ($aProductIds as $ids) {
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $aProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
            $prices[] = $aProduct->getPriceModel()->getPrice($aProduct);
        }
    }

    krsort($prices);
    $groupedProduct->setPrice(array_shift($prices));

    // or you can return price
}
```

Also you can prepare price with events, but this issue is the simplest way to get lowest group price.

Comment: thanks for the reply, $groupedProduct would be an array in my case would it not? How can I access getTypeInstance() on a non-object?

Comment: ignore that previous response. I've tried your code though and it crashes the page at the first variable ($aProductIds = $groupedProduct->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($groupedProduct->getId());
)

Comment: What error did you saw? $groupedProduct should be instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

Comment: @iamjonesy - You have an array because of `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getData()`, leave off the `getData()`. You ran into the same problem on a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4668215/471559).

Comment: Saved me some trouble with coming up with the same solution, mate. Cheers!

Comment: I know this is an older thread but I received more accurate results by changing getPrice to getFinalPrice.