# Get magento grouped product lowest price

Tags: magento

I have tried setting this up using this code [Magento: get the lowest price of a grouped product by product ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679123/magento-get-the-lowest-price-of-a-grouped-product-by-product-id) but cannot seem to get it working..

This is my current code, what would I need to do to get the lowest price from this grouped product??

```
            <?php
                    $cat_id = 33;
                    $catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
                    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
                $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');     
                    $collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model);
                    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','small_image', 'price')); //add product attribute to be fetched    
                    if(!empty($collection)) {?>
            <ul>
                    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
                <?php $i=0; foreach ($collection->getItems() as $_product): if($i==8){break;}?>
                <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?> 
                <?php endif ?>
                    <li class="span4"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product_image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(420); ?>" width="210" height="180"  alt="<?php echo $_product->getName();  ?>" /></a>

                        <span class="product_name"><?php echo $_product->getName();  ?></span> 

                        <span class="product_price">
                    <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(). sprintf('%.2f',$_product[price]) ;?>

                        <!--  WANT THE LOWEST PRICE HERE  -->

                        </span>

                        <a class="product_addto" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">View Product</a>

                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
                        <?php } else { echo 'No products exists';} ?>
```

Thank you in advance. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo round($_product->getPriceModel()->getMinimalPrice($_product),2);
```

hth

Comment: on Magento 1.92 getMinimalPrice doesn't exist in getPriceModel object